# PHPEXCEL in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, phpexcel

I am working in zend and in admin panel I have to export my data I am using `PHPExcel` for doing this here is the folder structure

```
Admin 
    src
       admin 
           Controller
    view
Vendor
    PhpExecl
    standard
        src
            standard 
                   static option
```

I am using `$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();` in static option

I am calling export function from my controller which is in the static option page but it is showing me 500 error

can you help

or if some body has a even better option then please post it

Comment: Enable PHP Errors; this is a symptom of an Fatal error.

Comment: What is your ZF version? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked with that lib the other day, make sure you include the path to the Phpexcel library classes in your php include paths:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.APPLICATION_PATH.'/your-path/phpexcel/Classes/');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to autoload PHPExcel classes. 
For sure a better option to avoid to have problems with autoload PHPExcel classes, and avoid to manual adding the classes in the include path, is to use [MvlabsPHPExcel](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsPHPExcel) that gives an easy integration of [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library into zend framework 2.